Can't set owner and group of udev rule
Below is the device for I want to create a symlink so can give it a name.

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-9:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9':
    KERNELS=="1-9"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="18"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Silicon Labs"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{product}=="CP2102N USB to UART Bridge Controller"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{serial}=="021f39d67f9aea11aa965eb3b9348ba5"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="9"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="12"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0504"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.4.0-200-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="140"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x9ded"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{index}=="5"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{label}=="Onboard - Other"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{irq}=="130"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x30"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x08af"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

I create the following udev rule:
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",KERNEL=="ttyUSB*",ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4",ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60",ATTRS{serial}=="021f39d67f9aea11aa965eb3b9348ba5",MODE="0660",OWNER="user",GROUP="dialout",SYMLINK+="PROG1"

And it created the symlink however I can't change it's owner and group.
user@user:/etc/udev/rules.d$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0 
crw-rw----+ 1 user dialout 188, 0 dez  3 10:57 /dev/ttyUSB0
user@user:/etc/udev/rules.d$ ls -la /dev/PROG1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 dez  3 10:57 /dev/PROG1 -> ttyUSB0


https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218559
